# Unity spritesheet or animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

Currently i'm drawing sprites for my game. I'm developing the game in unity for android.
So, the question is which way out of 2 is the best:
1. Create sprite, animate it in adobe after effects and export it as PNG sequence, then make a spritesheet for importing it in unity as frame-by-frame animation.
2. Create sprite, export it by parts (legs, head e.t.c.) and then make animation by default unity animation enviroment.

I'm interested which way will take less efforts and also which one will take less hard disk space in completed APK.

My head tells me that spritesheet requires more space but am i right? Also i would be happy to hear some advices from more skilled developers.

Didn't find a good topic at stackoverflow so decided to start my own.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want to achieve.

If you animate it inside Unity it will be easier to attach other things to each body part. For example if you wish to put a hat or some sunglasses on the head, they will follow the heads animation. On the contrary if you make the animations outside Unity you will have to animate each one individually, with the benefit of likely being able to make it look more unique.

In short, unity allows for reusing animations made in it but may look less pretty.

I also believe animating in Unity will take up less space, but I am not sure.

This (free) asset can help you animate it inside Unity: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-anima2d-79840